# What does "on the outlook" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Plus, if the euro weakens, as it should, on the outlook that economic hit will be softened dramatically.

Source: [Are Financial Markets Over-Exaggerating The Brexit Effect?](http://www.forbes.com/sites/bryanrich/2016/06/28/are-financial-markets-over-exaggerating-the-brexit-effect/#6e00c28c1b4e)

Comment: Have you looked up *outlook* in [a dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outlook)?

Answer (score 1):

In discussions of economies and business, ***outlook*** is a prediction about what is going to happen to economies and markets, or specific companies, in the future. It can be short-term or long-term.

Working out exactly what role it plays in that sentence is difficult, because the punctuation is confusing. If the sentence didn't end there, it might be saying that the Euro should weaken in response to the outlook is that the economic hit will be softened. That doesn't make sense semantically, and because of the *if* the sentence couldn't stop there - if that happened, then what?

However, if the comma after *should* were moved to after *outlook*, then it would be saying that the outlook is such that the Euro should weaken, and if it does then "that economic hit" (presumably a reference to a previous sentence) will be softened.